# Messed system paths and cannot start apps

Tags: macos, sudo, bash, system-paths

I edited /etc/paths, putting the local directories on top, and now I cannot run commands in terminal, including sudo, and am afraid this will affect the system outside terminal.

Trying to solve it, I have commented out everything and sourced .bash_profile and .bashrc, there is nothing under /etc/paths.d/, and /etc/paths is now:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

Yet the problem remains:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/.wp-cli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/bin:/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/.wp-cli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Volumes/Macintosh:/Volumes/Macintosh:/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/.wp-cli/bin
```

And:

```
$ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/.wp-cli/bin:/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Volumes/Macintosh"; export PATH;
```

System is Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. Looking forward to your help,

Comment: Can you run terminal commands using their full path names, e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: In my /etc/paths.d I have `/etc/paths.d/40-XQuartz`.  This just a one-line text file containing `/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: After returning the edited files/directories back to their previous state, I would imagine a full reboot would get you back to normal.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks. Under that path I only have /etc/paths.d/TeX. Should I have that X11? Yes, I can run apps with full path names. And, well, the behavior came along without rebooting so I am also hoping to revert it without. I risk not being able to log in.

Comment: In /etc/profile there is: # System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
 eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
 [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

Comment: $ source .bash_profile, the result is:
-bash: /Volumes/Macintosh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: /Volumes/Macintosh: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'

Comment: Most likely the X11 entry is only necessary if you running X11 apps (wireshark and xterm (not terminal) are examples I can think of).  Otherwise it is probably not a big deal

Comment: My /etc/profile is identical (assuming the SO comment box ate your newlines)

Comment: Can you provide line 1 of your .bash_profile?

Comment: Here are lines 1 and 2: PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" # Make sure to use double quotes not single quotes And on a new line ||
export PATH

Comment: Somehow it updated to the new settings after a while and I think it is back to normal now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still wonder if this output from 'echo $PATH' is healthy:
~/.wp-cli/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/.wp-cli/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/jsmm/.rvm/bin